# Обратиться к первому вложенному Div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, если нет классов у див, как обратиться к первому вложенному?
В данном случае, у меня применяется стиль ко всем вложенным div.

```css
.reply>div:first {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="reply">
    <div>
        <div>
            <p>first reply</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Я хочу применить стиль для первого вложенного div, но чтобы не применялся к следующему.
[image: Применить стиль только к этому div]

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько вариантов как это можно сделать в зависимости от задачи:

1. Если нужны `div`-ы, которые вложенны на первом уровне, то можно использовать [>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)

   ```css
   .reply > div {
     border-color: red;
   }

   div {
     border: 1px solid;
     margin: 10px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="reply">
     <div>
       <div>
         <p>first reply</p>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div>
       <div>
         <p>second reply</p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. Если нужен любой первый дочерний элемент, то можно использовать [`> :first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)

   ```css
   .reply > :first-child {
     border-color: red;
   }

   div, p {
     border: 1px solid;
     margin: 10px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="reply">
     <p>First paragraph</p>
     
     <div>
       <p>first reply</p>
     </div>
     
   </div>
   ```
3. Если нужен `div`, который первый дочерний элемент, то можно использовать [div:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)

   ```css
   .reply > div:first-child {
     border-color: red;
   }

   div, p {
     border: 1px solid;
     margin: 10px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="reply">
     <div>
       <div>
         <p>first reply</p>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div>
       <div>
         <p>second reply</p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```
4. Если среди всех вложенных дочерних нужен именно первый `div`, то можно использовать [:first-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)

   ```css
   .reply  div:first-of-type {
     border-color: red;
   }

   div, p {
     border: 1px solid;
     margin: 10px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="reply">
     <p>First paragraph</p>
     
     <div>
       <p>first reply</p>
     </div>
     
   </div>
   ```

Comment: Это прям хорошо сказанно